# gnuplot matrix datablock image

Tags: gnuplot

I have an ASCII file with multiple datablocks separated by newlines. Each datablock is the same size. I would like to plot each datablock as a separate heat map. I've been trying variations on the following command to plot the first block:

```
plot data matrix every :::0::0 w image
```

But gnuplot segfaults with this command. If I delete all datablocks except one, then I can plot that single block with

```
plot data matrix w image
```

How should I modify that first command to pick out an individual datablock? In the end, I would like to write a loop to produce individual plots for each datablock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my opinion there is a bit confusion about "datablock", "dataset", "data", etc...
If your "blocks" are separated by more than one empty line you can address it with `index`, check `help index`. If the "blocks" are separated by one line you can address them via `every`, check `help every`.

**Code:**

```
### plotting "datablocks"
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1  0
0  1


1  1
1  0


0  1
0  0


1  1
0  1
EOD

unset colorbox
set multiplot layout 2,2
    do for [i=0:3] {
        set title sprintf("Block %d",i)
        plot $Data index i matrix w image notitle
    }
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]